# Adjacency in procedural generation of dungeon

Tags: mathematics, procedural-generation

I wanted to make a procedural dungeon experimenting a new approach, it works nice for random-meaningless content (in example a procedural background to a level), however when I want it to be not-so-random I incur in some conceptual problem: basically I end up with a grid of numeric sector IDs in 2D.

Grid example:

```
27 |  56  | 74
---+------+----
35 |  31  | 115
---+------+----
14 |  52  | 12
```

The main problem is how to fix adjacency so that content is generated in a deterministic way:

- Content of sector "31" should be generated as a function of adjacent sectors (this works)
- However when I generate content for sector "35", I end up with a different link between sector "35" and "31".

So basically according from which direction I cross a sector I see a different passage each time (while the content of the sector is always the same).

As you see in the following image:

[image: Example of maps with connecting passages between sectors]

The passage between 35-31 is different according to which sector is used to start content generation, which is not what I want. I want the same passage arise.

To answer comments:

```
sector[id].content = generateContent( sector[id].neighboursIds());
```

Comment: I don't get the question... what do these numbers mean?

Comment: Could you explain in detail *how* you are generating the passages between sectors? Then we might be able to give a suggestion how it can be made deterministic no matter which order the sectors are in.

Comment: I think the question needs more details, from what I gather, all you need to use is re-use the existing link between sectors, if there is one there already.

Comment: @Ali.S those numbers are just sector ids, think that as to tile ids, in a tilemap they select the tile, in the procedural generator they choose a content type, while numbers of neighbours select additional content and passage to other sectors.

Comment: @Jon you are right! the problem is that links should be only function of 2 adiacent sectors (taken in same order) while actually it is not (function of 9 sectors right now), however that results in boring dungeons maybe I can workaround?

Comment: You likely need to override the `equals()` method for your link object class such that you `return (start == other.start && end == other.end) || (start == other.end && end == other.start)`

Comment: Are passages based on content or content is based on passages? Maybe you should first generate passages connecting all rooms in some way( your function), and then generate each room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is seed the passage according to the two sector ids being linked in numeric order.

```
function CalculateConnectionSeed ( sectorA, sectorB )
  if sectorA < sectorB
    return sectorA + sectorB * 16384
  else
    return sectorB + sectorA * 16384
endfunction
```

So no matter which way the connection is made the same seed will be used (16384 is just a number I picked to make sure sector 2+3 wont be the same as sectors 1+4 provided there are less than 16384 sector ids).

Or always generate the connection in the same direction: left-to-right or up-to-down.

Comment: Thanks, basically my error was using as part of the function the neighbours, though it produces interesting content, it is ureliable because changing neighbours => change the content. I'll revert to "link based solution" even if it provides less interesting content.